# How to write constraint function of coefficients conditional on other variables in a mixed frequency model in R?

Tags: r, midasr

I am trying to write a constrained function of coefficients in a mixed frequency model.
The mixed frequency model looks like below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MpXp.png)

briefly speaking, the dependent variable Y is a low-frequency variable that is observed once each year, and the independent variable X is a high-frequency variable that is observed each day, so each Y is matched with 365 X observations. I want to write the constraint function of coefficient beta as: beta is a function of other high-frequency variables: Beta = theta1*Z + theta2*W.
Do anybody know how to write above function in R? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried? Simply googling "mixed frequency model R" returns quite a few things.

Comment: Hi! I tried the MIDASR package, but it seems that it won't work. the constraint function is MIDASR package simply adds a sequence number in the constraint function, eg: from 1 to 365 that represents each high frequency day, and impose a mathematical weighting method (exponential, polynomial, etc). What I want to do is replace 1 to 365 sequential numbers by other variable observations from each one period, but it does not work...